# Create FB share dialog without image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Are there any ways to create share dialog without preview image?

If i don't specify og:image tag, it gets first image from page. 
Also tried specify small image (according to docs "The minimum image size is 200 x 200 pixels"), but it creates small preview.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no supported way to create a link share which doesn't have an image attached - that's the intended operation of sharing links on Facebook (manually, via the API, or otherwise) -

Your `og:image` or other meta tags should always specify an image which represents the URL being shared, or else Facebook (and other web services) will attempt to automatically detect an image to use instead